# Case created and owner change email notification from Process Builder

Tags: workflow, process-builder

When the case record is created, the approver receives a notification email indicating that a case has been sent for review and approval. How to do this in process builder ?
and also when owner is changed.

I wrote

```
OR((ISCHANGED([Case].OwnerId )), [Case].RecordType.name == "Contract Terms Esclations")
```

and Formula evaluates to true.

Case owner change email is triggering but not the case record cration email.

Comment: So there is this ISNEW() function which can tell you that why not simly use that function in criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct formula would be like below. I am checking the ownerId change and new case creation both in **OR** condition. I assume the record type name will be required in both the case.

```
AND(OR(ISCHANGED([Case].OwnerId ),ISNEW()) ,[Case].RecordType.Name =="Contract Terms Esclations" )
```

Whereas you were checking just owner has been changed or record type  name has been changed.

**Note :-**

> **[ISNEW](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5)**    Checks if the formula is running during the creation of a new record and returns TRUE if it is. If an existing record is being
>   updated, this function returns FALSE.